# Running java from php exec not working on IIS

Tags: java, php, iis

I can't exec a java command from php.

When calling other exe PHP are running fine.

I have tried some suggestions from other posts, with no success. If anybody can help I really appreciate.

I'm running IIS 7.5 on Win2008

```
exec("java -version", $output);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); echo "</pre>";
```

Array
(
)

```
exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe -version", $output);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); echo "</pre>";
```

Array
(
)

```
exec("whoami", $output);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); echo "</pre>";
```

Array
(
    [0] => iis apppool\defaultapppool
)

Comment: Is java on the path for the user your IIS is configured to run as?

Comment: java is on the path for my user, but I'm not sure if it is on the path for tue iis user IUSR. How can I check it?

Comment: Run a command that will echo `%PATH%` as the IIS user and look at the results.

Comment: The answer is: C:\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
Looks like java is not on IUSR path.
How can I add JAVA to IUSR path?

Comment: if you have permissions, add it to the SYSTEM path, so it will apply to all users. Otherwise, you can put the explicit path to Java in the PHP script itself.

Comment: Actually, I have tried that already and PHP still can't exec java.
I changed the post to add the command line with complete path